# increment output of pipe by 1 in shell

Tags: bash, pipe

eg:
`echo "abcdef_312345" | cut -b 9` --> output of this will be `1`, so I want to increase that by `1` in the same line.

Here's a template for the answer:

```bash
echo "abcdef_312345" | cut -b 9 | <command to increment by 1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
echo "abcdef_312345" | cut -b 9 | awk '{print $1 + 1}'
```

But `cut | awk` is an anti-pattern, so you should do:

```
echo "abcdef_312345" | awk '{print $9 + 1}' FS=
```

Comment: or just `awk '{print $9+1}' FS= <<< "abcdef_312345"`

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate the subprocess overhead:

```
$ x="abcdef_312456"
$ y=$(( ${x:8:1} + 1 ))
$ echo "${y}"
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo "abcdef_312345" | cut -b 9 | expr "$(cat)" + 1
```